# Deleting rows with less of 7 columns and with an empty second column

Tags: bash, awk

I need to delete from a csv, all the rows with less than 7 fields and also the rows with an empty second column

```
V8, 5,2015-01-14,3.7,-0.8,0.2,7.2
CT,,,,,,
R1, 6,2015-01-14,9.7,-1.0,0.0,14.4
Z8, 5 ,2015-01-14,1.4,-4.0,0.1,54.4
XL, 5,2015-01-14,15.0,6.4,0.0,27.7
D9, 6,2015-01-14,16.4,2.6,0.0,34.6
XM, 6,2015-01-14,2.2,-0.2,0.2,9.0
ZC, 5 ,2015-01-14,
,
,
```

I have 7 fields (columns)

```
awk -F',' '{print NF; exit}' 2015-01-14.csv 
7
```

I have tried the next command in order to delete rows with less than 7 fields/columns, but doesn't run

```
awk -F"," 'NF>=7' 2015-01-14.csv
```

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't run"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean it doesn't work

Comment: Either way, it's worth being clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: does this work there? `awk -F, 'NF>=7&&$2' file`

Comment: Q: `What do you mean "doesn't run"?` A: `Sorry, I mean it doesn't work`. Classic :-). @Kent, that'd fail if $2 was populated with a value that evaluated numerically to zero.

Comment: @EdMorton exactly! I neglected that part.... shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below,

```
$ awk -F, 'NF>=7 && $2 != ""' file
V8, 5,2015-01-14,3.7,-0.8,0.2,7.2
R1, 6,2015-01-14,9.7,-1.0,0.0,14.4
Z8, 5 ,2015-01-14,1.4,-4.0,0.1,54.4
XL, 5,2015-01-14,15.0,6.4,0.0,27.7
D9, 6,2015-01-14,16.4,2.6,0.0,34.6
XM, 6,2015-01-14,2.2,-0.2,0.2,9.0
```

This prints the rows which has 7 or more fields and  also the second field wouldn't be empty.